# Why does my Ruby on Rails project break when I attempt to deploy it to Heroku?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sqlite

here's the long and the end of it. My project was originally made in SQLite3, and because Heroku does not accept SQLite3, I converted the project o PosgreSQL and attempted to deploy the project online. However, all of my assets break, I can only see my HTML font and NONE of my pictures or animations. Below is an uploaded video of my issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnIXWWk2no4

Keep in  mind. This project has NO stored information. The project is literally all just HTML, CSS, and Jquery. That's seriously about it. No database relationships, no stored information, nothing. When I made this project I was a newbie coder (still am), and I only used Ruby on Rails cause that was what I was familiar with at the time. In any case, does anyone have any thoughts on what the issue might be?

Comment: There's not much information here for us to work with. Have you looked at your Heroku deploy logs, particularly around asset precompilation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: I haven't Jonah, I'll take a look at this

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remove turbolinks gem from your application this is how to do this:

- Remove the gem 'turbolinks' line from your Gemfile.
- Remove the //= require turbolinks from your app/assets/javascripts/application.js.
- Remove the two "data-turbolinks-track" => true hash key/value pairs from your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.